# How to replace a Video in Google Slides with another (or simply replace the URL)

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a presentation in Google Slides that includes a Video from Drive. I'd like to use an Apps Script to programmatically replace this Video with another, also from Drive.

There are two ways I thought I could approach this:

1. Change the URL of the existing video in the presentation.
2. Remove the existing video and insert a new one.

Unfortunately (1) won't work because even though there is a `getUrl` method for `Video`, there is no corresponding `setUrl` method. In fact, I realised that for a `Video` that has been inserted from Drive, `getUrl` returns `null`. You can only use `getVideoId` to get the Drive id for that video.

I couldn't get (2) to work either. There is an `insertVideo` method for `Slide` but it will only work for YouTube videos or for videos that exist in other slides or presentations.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the video cannot be directly replaced on the Google Slides. So in my case, as a simple workaround, I prepare a storage Google Slides including the videos which is used for replacing. This Google Slides is not the main Google Slides. This is used as the storage of videos. And when I want to replace the video in the main Google Slides, I replace the page of the main Google Slides with the page of the strage Google Slides. By this, the video can be replaced. I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want. So I posted this as a comment.

Comment: This will not work in my case but thanks for the comment @Tanaike.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way of doing it, as you said first option is not possible, and second is not available for Drive, only for Youtube.

I've tried possible workarounds based on the Drive API, specifically modifying the original video binary file with the content of the new one so we could keep the same ID and thus change the video on slides, but it does not work either, don't waste your time trying.

At this point, what I recommend is to submit a Feature request to add the setUrl method on Slides API, or to be able to change the VideoId.

On here you'll be able to do it, remember to add this post over the request.

https://issuetracker.google.com

Comment: I have filed an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144151360. Thanks for the suggestion. I will report here if any new info arises.